# In excel cannot get the column header of a minimum value in the row when empty cells exist

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to get the following when searching for minimum value winner

[image]

But I have empty cells and the minimum winner is allways the first empty

I tried for example with the

```
=INDEX($B$2:$O$2;MATCH(MIN(B30:O30);B30:O30;0))
```

How can I overcome the empty cells keep the cells where number exist and find my winner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those cells aren't blank; they are zeroes with a custom currency format that shows a hyphen with the euro symbol.

```
=index($B$2:$O$2, match(aggregate(15, 7, B30:O30/(B30:O30<>0), 1), B30:O30, 0))
=index($B$2:$O$2; match(aggregate(15; 7; B30:O30/(B30:O30<>0), 1); B30:O30; 0))
```

AGGREGATE is being used as a psuedo-MINIF function. Newer versions of Excel also have the native MINIFS worksheet function.

Comment: Note: MINIFS was introduced in Excel 2016, but is only available to Office 365 subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this may suit:

```
=INDEX($1:$1;MATCH(AGGREGATE(5;3;A2:E2);A2:E2;0))
```